# Nanoscroller auto update scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, nanoscroller

i have a nanoscroller on a data table but when i search data i want to update de nanoscroller scroll bar.
i am running a script on update input field but that does not work.

```
$('input[type=search]').change(function () {
    $(".nano").nanoScroller();
});
```

i cant find a solution on internet so i hope someone has dealt with this before.

I have a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/orqwooz6/1/

Much Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem it is in the

```
$('input[type=search]').change(function () {
    $(".nano").nanoScroller();
});
```

i have changed it to

```
$('.search').on('input', function() {
  $(".nano").nanoScroller();
});
```